# How to match specific tokens in UIMA Ruta?

Tags: uima, ruta

```
DECLARE A,B;
DECLARE Annotation C(Annotation firstA, Annotation secondA,...);
"token1|token2|...|tokenn" -> A;
"token3|token4" -> B;

A A B {->MARK(C,1,3)};
```

I did with GATHER

```
(A  COMMA A B) {-> GATHER(C,1,4,"firstA"=1,"secondA" = 3,"B"=4)};
```

But how about in case of unknown sequence of A type? as below, how can it be possible to store all A in features? The number of features are also unknown. In plan java, we declare String array and can add element, but in Ruta seems to be no as such process.

```
(A  (COMMA A)+ B) {-PARTOF(C) -> GATHER(C,beginPosition,endPosition,"firstA"=1,"secondA" = 3,"thirdA"=?,so on)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations in UIMA refer to the complete span, from the begin offset to the end offset. So, if you want to specify something with two elements, then a simple annotation is not sufficient. You cannot create an annotation of the type C that covers the first A and the B but not the second A.

However, you can store the important information in feature values. How to implement it depends on various things.

If there are always exactly two annotation you want to remember, then add two features to type C and assign the feature values in the given rule, e.g., by CREATE(C,1,3,"first" = A, "second" = B ).

You can also use different actions like GATHER, or use one FSArray feature in order to store the annotations.

A complete example with a FSArray:

```
DECLARE A, B;
DECLARE Annotation C (FSArray as, B b);
"A" -> A;
"B" -> B;
(A (COMMA A)+ B){-PARTOF(C) -> CREATE(C, "as" = A, "b" = B)};
```

If applied on a text like "A, A, A B", the last rule creates one annotation of type C that stores three A annotations in the feature "as" and one B annotation in the feature "b"

Comment: I did with GATHER as there is also tutorial on Ruta webpage. However, I am now stuck on another question (edited question). In case of unknown sequence of any Type, how to store them all in features of related types. Features are also arbitrary.

Comment: My first guess: use a FSArray feature and the CREATE action. The action notices that the feature is able to store more than one annotation and then assigns all type A annotations within the matched window to the feature. I will extend the answer later.

Comment: The create action by default only takes first annotation. For e.g. in above e.g. if in feature I put A, then it will be the first A only. Anyway, now I am interested in getting only the last annotation and put in feature using CREATE. So if in above e.g. the B is also A but as it is in the end, how to get that last A and put in as feature of C annotation?

Comment: One dirty solution I tried is loop over all A for that particular C and when loop stops, the last which I stored in any String can be used. There seem to be no standard way to get last by index as in plain Java.

Comment: Yes, there is no standard way yet. What I normally do is to annotate the the last A with a subtype of A like Alast: ((A COMMA)+ A{-> Alast} B){-> CREATE(C, "as" = A, "last" = Alast, "b" = B)};